# Select the row with a certain accumulated value MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table:

```
--------------
| id | value |
--------------
| 1  | 5     |
--------------
| 2  | 2     |
--------------
| 3  | 7     |
--------------
| 4  | 8     |
--------------
```

I want to find the first row, as ordered by `id`, that would exceed an accumulated sum of 10. In this case, it would be row 3, as 5 + 2 + 7 is greater than 10 (for the `value` column).

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you always order by the id column (if not, this wouldn't be possible as sql in unordered), then here's one option:

```
select *
from yourtable t
where exists (select 1 
              from yourtable t2
              where t2.id <= t.id
              having sum(value) > 10)
order by id
limit 1
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/03f03/1)

Answer (score 0):

Probably the fastest way is to use variables:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, (@s := @s + value) as sumv
      from t cross join
           (select @s := 0)
      order by id
     ) t
where sumv - value <= 10 and sumv > 10;
```